# Internal server error using Rcurl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I want to use the following curl command using RCurl

```
curl -X POST http://test.reco4j.org:7474/db/data/ext/Reco4jRecommender/node/248/get_recommendations -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type":"0"}'
```

so i am using the following R code

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
postForm("http://test.reco4j.org:7474/db/data/ext/Reco4jRecommender/node/248/get_recommendations",
         .opts = list(postfields = toJSON(list(id = "0")),
                      httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
                      ))
```

But I get an "Internal server errror", so i am not sure my R code is wrong or it is a windows problem.
The reason I am mentioning this, is that the original curl command fails in windows but works on mac and Linux, so I am not sure the R failure is a windows issue or an R issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code. The pair you need to send is `"type":"0"` you are sending `"id":"0"`.

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
res <- postForm("http://test.reco4j.org:7474/db/data/ext/Reco4jRecommender/node/248/get_recommendations",
         .opts = list(postfields = toJSON(list(type = "0")),
                      httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
                      ))
out <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res))

> head(out[[1]])
$outgoing_relationships
[1] "http://test.reco4j.org:7474/db/data/node/2285/relationships/out"

$data
$data$movieId
[1] 1342

$data$title
[1] "Convent, The (Convento, O) (1995)"

$data$releaseDate
[1] "14-Jun-1996"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bad URL. I get an `HTTP ERROR 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` trying to access that URL in firefox.

EDIT: Disregard, you're right: the curl command worked in a shell prompt. Sorry for doubting you.

Comment: But when I run the command from Linux or mac , it works fine.

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same error:
 
Error: Internal Server Error
4. stop(err)
3. stop.if.HTTP.error(http.header)
2. postForm(url, id = "j1", p = data, n = "compute-pi")
1. progress(i, tot)

this is how i am using postForm:
url <- "http://localhost:3000/progressR"
  data <- percent
  #rCurlReqest
  form <- postForm(url, id = "j1", p = data, n = "compute-pi")
  print(percent)

Can i get any help in that!